# When using html() or text() closing html tags do not show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I am trying to receive messages, and when I do, it works for the most part except for the fact that the html closing tags do not return (`</div>`,`</p>`, etc). I use jquery's `html()`, and I have used `text()` to verify that the closing tags don't return. Here is my code:

```
function formatMessages(data) {

var dataArray = data.split("\n");
var messages = "";
for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
dataArray[i] = dataArray[i].split(":");
}
for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
messages +=   '<div class="chatMessage"><h3 class="chatName">'+dataArray[i][0]+":</h3> ";
messages += '<h4 class="chatContent">'+dataArray[i][1]+'</h4>';
var timeDate = moment(dataArray[i][2]*1000).format("M/D/YY");
var timeMinute = moment(dataArray[i][2]*1000).format("m");
var timeHour = moment(dataArray[i][2]*1000).format("H");
if(timeHour>12) {
    timeHour -=12;
    var ampm = "pm"
}
else {
    ampm = "am"
}
messages += '<h6 class="chatTime">'+ timeHour + ':' + timeMinute +'<span class="chatAmpm">' + ampm +'</span> (' + timeDate + ')</h6></div>';
}
return messages;
}
```

And I implement it with:

```
$('#messages').html(formatMessages(data));
```

The 'messages' tag:

```
<div id="messages"></div>
```

Example of data:

```
Kyle Donoghue:g:1490379471
Kyle Donoghue:hell:1490379481
Kyle Donoghue:llklkl:1490380511
Kyle Donoghue:ljnlkn:1490380512
```

And the output:

```
<div class="chatMessage"><h3 class="chatName">Kyle Donoghue: <h4 class="chatContent">g<h6 class="chatTime">11:17<span class="chatAmpm">am (3/24/17)<div class="chatMessage"><h3 class="chatName">Kyle Donoghue: <h4 class="chatContent">hell<h6 class="chatTime">11:18<span class="chatAmpm">am (3/24/17)<div class="chatMessage"><h3 class="chatName">Kyle Donoghue: <h4 class="chatContent">llklkl<h6 class="chatTime">11:35<span class="chatAmpm">am (3/24/17)<div class="chatMessage"><h3 class="chatName">Kyle Donoghue: <h4 class="chatContent">ljnlkn<h6 class="chatTime">11:35<span class="chatAmpm">am (3/24/17)
```

Comment: Works fine here. Can you show how you confirmed it with `.text()`? Maybe with a runnable snippet?

Comment: `.text()` doesn't return any tags.

Comment: I cannot make a runnable snippet at the moment, but if you want, I can comment the url this code runs at...

Comment: Could you show a sample for "data"?

Comment: i edited it to show an example... @eldes

Comment: I made a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/qrKeVL?editors=1010) using your code and data sample. I can't reproduce the issue. Closing tags are there.

Comment: I (kind of) fixed it by just completely avoiding it. Instead of using strings, I generated the elements with jQuery and then just appended them to the parent element. Thanks for you help though!

Comment: Closing tags there too: <div class="chatMessage"><h3 class="chatName">Kyle Donoghue:</h3> <h4 class="chatContent">g</h4><h6 class="chatTime">3:17<span class="chatAmpm">pm</span> (3/24/17)</h6></div>